# Embedded flash player doesn't load

Tags: c#, flash

I wrote a program in C# that, when a user press a button, opens a new form containing an embedded flash object. The flash application needs the user to be logged in, so i added to the source something like

```
swf.SetVariable("__ses", sid);
```

This works fine for 2 user testing the application, while the third one can succesfully open one table, while all the others appear "black", just like if the loader can't get past the loading step.
Has anyone had before a similar issue? or has somebody a suggestion on how to debug this problem? I can't figure out if the problem is in the program, or in some strange flash setting he may have... thank you

Comment: Without more information or code, we won't be able to figure this one out, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging I would suggest putting trace statements in various points of the swf to see where it fails.

http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/ is a great tool for viewing flash traces from the browser.

If the flash app needs a login variable to actually work and proceed the variable might not be being passed properly. Passing variables to swfs can be a pain because different browsers have different requirements.
Luckily theres this great library that address's these problems and assures your variables get passed properly each and every time.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

So maybe trace out the session id. If it does not trace that might be why its not getting past the loading step. Then try out swfobject.